# Printing 2D Array outputs adresses

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, printf

I tried to print a 2D Array but the output containts random integers. I am unsure what causes this problem since I am new to C and suspect it has something to do with memory management.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int map[10][10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            printf("%d ",map[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect this code to output a 10x10 matrix of 0 but instead I get a mix of 0 and random integers. I am not sure what is causing this, I suspect that the program operates out of its dedicated memory but I am new to C and do not understand why it does that.

*Example Output:*

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 8388608 0 
-1819386832 32765 -1819386840 32765 592768165 32694 786432 0 2048 0 
0 0 32768 0 786432 0 8192 0 1048576 0 
32768 0 2 0 14 -2147483648 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
6 142 12 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
592799968 32694 13 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 
1417023552 21882 592791612 32694 2032 0 -1819385479 32765 -1818730496 32765 
16777216 257 2 0 -1075053569 0 -1819385463 32765 100 0
```

Comment: TL;DR: `map` is uninitialized. Attempting to read from it before writing a value is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/11082165). Anything can happen, including your program printing all zeros, printing garbage values, or [causing demons to fly out of your nose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Answer (score 1):

Your array is uninitialized. You're printing whatever random values were in that memory, interpreted as `int` values. Now, you might by chance on a run of your program get all zeroes, but that can't be counted on.

If you want to ensure it's zeroed, either explicitly initialize it as such, make it `static`, or make it a global variable (but don't use global variables if you can avoid it). In the latter two cases, it will be initialized to zero without explicitly writing the initialization.

The explicit initialization isn't much of a modification.

```
int map[10][10] = {0};
```

Comment: Thanks I thought all values would be 0 by default

Comment: @Randaniel: One of the things that makes C fast is that it doesn't do a lot of stuff behind the scenes; it doesn't initialize automatic variables to 0 (or any other value) unless you explicitly tell it to.  Otherwise they start out with whatever bit pattern was last written to that chunk of memory.  `static` variables are initialized to 0, but that happens when the program is first loaded into memory so there's little to no runtime cost.